# Find connected objects using GetProperties() on EF objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

```
var properties = from p in typeof(T).GetProperties()
                 && p.PropertyType.IsByRef
                 select p;
```

I'm trying to filter the properties that are connected EF tables using the snippet above. The problem seems to be `p.PropertyType.IsByRef`, since I don't get any matches. The type above is one of my EF classes.

How do I distinguish between connected tables and properties like strings, integers, bools etc?

Comment: ref tables are hashset if i m not wrong .. or any kind of set.. so you can get properties which are of collection types(ienumerable) this way you get things

Answer (score 0):

Use `IsValueType` instead of `IsByRef`.  `IsByRef` refers to a parameter being passed into a method either by ref or by value.

Comment: No joy. Checking the type for collections seems to be my best option so far.